# How to convert DateTime? to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to convert a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`)  to a `DateTime`, but I am getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to
>   'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

I have attempted the following:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = (DateTime)_objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate == null 
    ? DateTime.Now : _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate;
```

Answer (score 360, accepted):

You want to use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), which is designed for exactly this purpose.

Using it you end up with this code.

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: here is a snippet I used within a Presenter filling a view with a Nullable Date/Time :  `memDateLogin = m.memDateLogin ?? DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: 'DateTime?' dose not contain definition for 'UpdatedDate'

Answer (score 98):

MS already made a method for this, so you dont have to use the null coalescing operator. No difference in functionality, but it is easier for non-experts to get what is happening at a glance.

```
DateTime updatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 44):

Try this

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: The key thing here is the null-coalescing operator, see chills42's answer more information.

Answer (score 35):

You can use a simple cast:

```
DateTime dtValue = (DateTime) dtNullAbleSource;
```

You have to check if the var is null before

Comment: Perfect if you check if the var is null before +1

Answer (score 27):

You need to call the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(VS.80).aspx) property of the nullable DateTime. This will return a DateTime.

Assuming that `UpdatedDate` is `DateTime?`, then this should work:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = (DateTime)_objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate == null ? DateTime.Now : _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.Value;
```

To make the code a bit easier to read, you could use the [HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(VS.80).aspx) property instead of the `null` check:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.HasValue
                          ? _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.Value
                          : DateTime.Now;
```

This can be then made even more concise:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 6):

How about the following:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.HasValue ? _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.value : DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a snippet I used within a Presenter filling a view with a Nullable Date/Time

```
memDateLogin = m.memDateLogin ?? DateTime.MinValue
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Nullable(T) Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19twx9w9.aspx):

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.HasValue 
    ? DateTime.Now : _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following which its far better than the accepted answer

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate == null 
    ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime)_objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate;
```

Comment: Care to say *why* its better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = (DateTime)_objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate == null ? DateTime.Now : _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = _objHotelPackageOrder.HasValue ? _objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate.Value : DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct.

Comment: @MaximilianAst yes you are right will try to implement the way you have suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [IS operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(is_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) starting with C# 7.0:

```
DateTime UpdatedTime = (_objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate is DateTime myDate) ? myDate : DateTime.Now;
```

Or in a case distinction

```
if (_objHotelPackageOrder.UpdatedDate is DateTime UpdatedTime)
{
   ...
}
```

For the sake of completeness.