# How to convert DateTime? to DateTime in C# and how to compare the two dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert a DateTime? value to DateTime  value. And compare DateTime value with DateTime.MaxValue in C#. Even though the values are same. I'm getting -1 for the DateTime comparison. I'm new to C#. Where am I going wrong in the following code?

I have searched and found this related link on stack overflow. But I don't know how to fix it:
[How to convert DateTime? to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091870/how-to-convert-datetime-to-datetime)

```
private DateTime? expires = null;

public DateTime? DateExpires {
    get
    {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DateTime Max Value: " + DateTime.MaxValue);
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Date expires: " + expires);
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Date expires value: " + expires.Value);

         if (expires.HasValue)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I have some value");
             DateTime dtime = expires.Value;
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dtime value: " + dtime);

             int result = DateTime.Compare(dtime, DateTime.MaxValue);
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Compared result: " + result);

         } else
         {    
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I don't have any value");
         }

         return expires.Value;
     }
     set
     {
          expires = value;
     } 
}
```

Here are my results for the code:

```
DateTime Max Value: 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM
Date expires: 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM
Date expires value: 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM
I have some value
Dtime value: 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM
Compared result: -1
```

Update:

In one of the methods, the value of `expires` is set

```
_model.expires = _model.expires != null ? _model.expires.Value : DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Comment: Your question is super unclear:) you may compare your `DateTime?` and `DateTime` like any others variables (i.e. `dateTime1 == dateTime2`). Just be aware that when your `DateTime?` is `null` - any compare with `DateTime` will be `false`. You may also handle default value for this case like this: `nullableDateTime ?? DateTime.Now == dateTime1`

Comment: What's the calling code look like?  I just ran your code in LinqPad, setting `DateTime? expires = DateTime.MaxValue`, and the compare result returns `0`.

Comment: @vasily.sib if `expires` is `null`, the current code throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I'm not talking about current code at all, but you are right, if `expires.HasValue == false`, then `return expires.Value;` will throw `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: I would suggest you when comparing convert both of them to universal time and compare there is no need to converting from DateTime? because you can get its value by  expires.Value. Or for comparing you can write a custom logic where you will be comparing against Year, Month, Date, Hour, Min, Sec, Timezone etc.

Comment: debug, check `(DateTime.MaxValue - dtime).TotalMilliseconds` and you will see the difference between this values.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Should I add more code to the question?

Comment: @vasily.sib - yes, you're right. There is 3.3332 millisecs difference between the two values. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datetimes are different in some way.  May be at the millisecond level?  Maybe the TimeZone or the UTC kind.

They are definitely different one way or another.  Nullable datetimes return a DateTime object in their Value property so no conversion is required.

Comment: What I did mean by my comment is that your answer is not an answer at all (I didnt mean that you should remove _"My guess"_ literaly). Your answer is still just a guess, and there is a comments for guesses (to conform to the rules and guidelines of stackoverflow)

Comment: @vasily.sib your comment is irrelevant and is pure cosmetics.  Bottom line is if DateTime.Compare returns anything other tan 0 then the values being compared are different.  That is irrefutable.  Lastly there is no "conversion" from Nullable datetime; since it holds a DateTime value in its Value property and you can check for null using HasValue. So the answer is perefectly fine.

Comment: Ok, then about your answer specificly. First: `DateTime` doesn't know anything about TimeZones and doesn't hold this information inside. Second: Nullable datetimes throws a `InvalidOperationException` in their `Value` property when they are equal to `null` (when their `HasValue` property is equal to `false`).

Comment: @Darkonekt Yes, there is a 3.3332 millisecs difference between the two values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @vasily.sib wrong again!  DateTimes have the Timezone in the form of UTC Kind.  Your datetime can be either local time or utc. Therefore they do contain in some shape the timezone information.  So when you construct your datetime for comparison you need to be careful that both of them end up being either local or UTC.....

Comment: @Darkonekt you contradict yourself. If `DateTime` actually contains information about TimeZone, why does `clr` do not use it in comparison? For example with `DateTimeOffset` (which actually stores timezone information inside) you can do this: `var d = DateTimeOffset.Now; var d2 = d.ToUniversalTime(); var res = d == d2; // true` See? `clr` is smart enough to check timezones in this case. Are you talking about `DateTime.Kind`? It's just a flag showing _"do I call ToUniversalTime() or ToLocalTime()"_. In short `DateTime` is used when you don't care about TimeZones, `DateTimeOffset` - when you do.

Comment: @vasily.sib the one contradicting himself is you..... And the question is not about datetimeoffset........

Comment: @Darkonekt c'mon. It takes almost 11 days to say _"no, you"_? `DateTimeOffset` is here just as an **example** of type, that actually store timezone information within. That's why I prepend it with _"For **example** with ..."_.